# How to integrate LazyBones with VCS?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, code-generation, scaffolding

I just learned about [LazyBones](https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones) and absolutely love it! The problem is that it generates a "code skeleton" for you **before** your app's VCS repo exists. And I see there is *some* integration capability with Git, but what about other VCSes?

Specifically, I'm using Mercurial. So ordinarily, I'd create the hg repo for my new app (on the server), clone it out locally, and some code to the cloned working copy, commit & push it.

So I ask: what is the proper workflow (or set of commands) to create a new app from a LazyBones template **and** integrate it with a new hg repo?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, slightly more elegant way *may be*:

- Generate skeleton by LazyBones in `SomeDir`
- Init Mercurial repo after it in `SomeDir`
- Add needed files from working directory into (empty) repository
- Create remote repo on server
- Add remote repository URL into `[path]` section of local repo's .hgrc (maybe also auth. credential into `[auth]`)
- Push

Comment: Thanks @Lazy Badger (+1) - so if I understand you correctly, after running `lazybones create myTmpl myapp`, drop into the `myapp` directory, run `hg init` to create a repo there, then `hg add` to add all the files of the working copy into the repo, then **manually** (not via command line) go to the server and create the remote repo, then modify `.hgrc`, and then finally `hg push`? If this is correct, do you believe this is scriptable (besides the server-side part)? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja - yes, correct. Just one note (my mistake) - .hgrc after init doesn't exist at all, thus - creating it with two lines is rather obvious task (even in Windows). And yes, it's easy scriptable (if step 4 "Create remote repo on server" will be step 0 I'll write short-liner with two parameters - PATH and URL in minutes)